# Lock wait timeout exceeded with Hibernate and MySQL (using play framework)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

In my web application I'm using `Stateless sessions` with `Hibernate` to have better performances on my `inserts` and `updates`.

It was working fine with `H2 database` (the one used in *play framework* in dev mode).

But when I test it with `MySQL` I get the following exception :

```
ERROR ~ Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
ERROR ~ HHH000315: Exception executing batch [Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
```

Here is the code :

```
public static void update() {
    Session session = (Session) JPA.em().getDelegate();
    StatelessSession stateless = this.session.getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();

        try {

            stateless.beginTransaction();

            // Fetch all products
            {
                List<ProductType> list = ProductType.retrieveAllWithHistory();
                for (ProductType pt : list) {
                    updatePrice(pt, stateless);
                }
            }

            // Fetch all raw materials
            {
                List<RawMaterialType> list = RawMaterialType.retrieveAllWithHistory();
                for (RawMaterialType rm : list) {
                    updatePrice(rm, stateless);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            play.Logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            ExceptionLog.log(ex, Thread.currentThread());
        } finally {
            stateless.getTransaction().commit();
            stateless.close();
        }
}

private static void updatePrice(ProductType pt, StatelessSession stateless) {
    pt.priceDelta = computeDelta();
    pt.unitPrice = computePrice();

    stateless.update(pt);

    PriceHistory ph = new PriceHistory(pt, price);

    stateless.insert(ph);
}

private static void updatePrice(RawMaterialType rm, StatelessSession stateless) {
    rm.priceDelta = computeDelta();
    rm.unitPrice = computePrice();

    stateless.update(rm);

    PriceHistory ph = new GoodPriceHistory(rm, price);

    stateless.insert(ph);
}
```

In this example I have 3 simple *Entities* (`ProductType`, `RawMaterialType` and `PriceHistory`).
`computeDelta` and `computePrice` are just algorithm functions with no DB stuff.
`retrieveAllWithHistory` functions are functions that fetch some data from the database using `Play framework model` functions.

So, this code retrieves some data, edit some, create new one and finally save everything.

Why have I a lock exception with `MySQL` and no exception with `H2` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a commit in a `finally` block. Give this structure a try:

```
try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

Also, it might be helpful for you to check this [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged).

Comment: Actually, the exception is thrown during the call to `stateless.insert(ph);` (after the call to `stateless.update(ph);`). So the commit function is not even called yet (even if put inside the try statement)

Comment: Try this: comment the update and run it again. I faced a similar situation before and the first transaction didn't rollback and the second produced the lock timeout exception. If the insert doesn't throw the exception it is likely that you are missing the rollback there.

Comment: I tried deleting one of the insert or update function and there is no exception thrown. I don't understand what's happening... MySQL does not support updates AND inserts in the same transaction ?